# Redmine API Users in Groups

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I am Making a wpf app that shows some data from redmine using Redmine.Net.Api.
I just want to display users that belong to redmine Groups. 
I can get all groups

```
Redminemanager manager = new RedmineManager(Config.host, Config.apiKey);
var groups = manager.GetObjects<Group>();
```

I get groups names right, but the users are always Null.

I tried too the Groups under User class:

```
 Redminemanager manager = new RedmineManager(Config.host, Config.apiKey);
  var redmineUsers = manager.GetObjects<User>()
```

Groups there are always null too.

I don't get this, I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about how the Redmine REST API works: by default, listing a group **WONT** retrieve the users.

The Redmine [REST API documentation, GET Groups section](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Groups#GET-2), says:

> **GET**
>
> Returns details of a group.
>
> This endpoint requires admin privileges.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - include (optional): a coma separated list of associations to include in the response:
>
>   - users
>   - memberships

I tried a `GET /groups/1.json` on my local Redmine installation without the `include=users` and actually doesn't retrieve the users. When I add the `?include=users` it works like a charm

On the [official Redmine.Net.API Wiki on Github](https://github.com/zapadi/redmine-net-api/wiki/Add-user-to-group) there is an example using these include parameters.

It's something like this:

```
var group = manager.GetObject<Group>(groupId, 
                                new NameValueCollection() { { RedmineKeys.INCLUDE, RedmineKeys.USERS } });
```

Good luck.